# Ripple effect is not working for WebView android

Tags: android, material-design

I have a webview inside linear layout. Added ripple background to the webview.
Also make that clickabe.

No background is showing.

After adding setBackgroundColor 0x0000000, a background is showing but ripple is not working.

Comment: Show some code. That will help us understand what you want to achieve by "ripple effect for WebView".

Comment: You can't have a background color and background drawable at the same time. Its one or the other i'm pretty sure.

Comment: Consider a webview where to show some cms content, Also a touch function there

Comment: Background drawable only working after adding that alpha background color